# Databricks Autoloader is getting stuck and does not pass to the next batch

Tags: spark-streaming, databricks, autoload, rocksdb, mini-batch

I have a simple job scheduled every 5 min. Basically it listens to cloudfiles on storage account and writes them into delta table, extremely simple. The code is something like this:

```
df = (spark
  .readStream
  .format("cloudFiles")
  .option('cloudFiles.format', 'json')
  .load(input_path, schema = my_schema)
  .select(cols)
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("checkpointLocation", f"{output_path}/_checkpoint")
  .trigger(once = True)
  .start(output_path))
```

Sometimes there are new files, sometimes not. After 40-60 batches it gets stuck on one particular batchId, as if there are no new files in the folder. If i run the script manually i get the same result: it points to the last actually processed batch.

```
{
  "id" : "xxx,
  "runId" : "xxx",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2022-01-13T15:25:07.512Z",
  "batchId" : 64,
  "numInputRows" : 0,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "durationMs" : {
    "latestOffset" : 663,
    "triggerExecution" : 1183
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "CloudFilesSource[/mnt/source/]",
    "startOffset" : {
      "seqNum" : 385,
      "sourceVersion" : 1,
      "lastBackfillStartTimeMs" : 1641982820801,
      "lastBackfillFinishTimeMs" : 1641982823560
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "seqNum" : 385,
      "sourceVersion" : 1,
      "lastBackfillStartTimeMs" : 1641982820801,
      "lastBackfillFinishTimeMs" : 1641982823560
    },
    "latestOffset" : null,
    "numInputRows" : 0,
    "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
    "metrics" : {
      "numBytesOutstanding" : "0",
      "numFilesOutstanding" : "0"
    }
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "DeltaSink[/mnt/db/table_name]",
    "numOutputRows" : -1
  }
}
```

But if I run only the readStream part - it correctly reads the entire list of files ( and starts a new batchId: 0 ). The strangest part is: I have absolutely no Idea what causes it and why it takes around 40-60 batches to get this kind of error. Can anyone help? Or give me some suggestion?
I was thinking about using ForeachBatch() to append new data. Or using trigger `.trigger(continuous='5 minutes')`

I'm new to AutoLoader

Thank you so much!

Comment: How files are put into cloud storage? Maybe they are updated or overwritten instead of creating new files?

Comment: Greetings Alex, thank you for helping. The files are output of Azure Function that is a subscriber of Azure Service Bus. Basically it goes like this:
Service Bus Queue (AVRO) --> Azure Function (AVRO --> JSON) --> Azure Blob Storage --> Delta Table.
Each file has a timestamp in its name so no 2 files with equal names and there should be no overwrites or update. I was thinking about a simple solution and this one came to my mind

Comment: I remade the job in Scala with new tigger `.trigger(Trigger.AvailableNow)` and got the same result after just 34 batches. What is going on? My checkpoint folder is in the same folder as my delta table (which is Data Lake 2.0 on Azure)

It seems like rocksdb is registring new rows as added while passing nothing to the table

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using

`.option('cloudFiles.useIncrementalListing', 'false')`

My filenames are composed of flowname + timestamp, like this:

`flow_name_2022-01-18T14-19-50.018Z.json`
So my guess is: some combination of dots make the rocksdb go into non-existing directory, that's why the it reports that "found no new files". Once I disabled incremental listing rocksdb stopped making its mini checkpoints based on filenames and now reads the whole directory. This is the only explanation that I have.
If anyone is having the same issue try changing the filename